# run django projact from another python program

Tags: android, python, django, server, kivy

are anyway to run django project from another python program without useing subprocess or os.system.

im trying to use :

```
os.system("python manage.py runserver")
```

and :

```
subprocess.call("python", "manage.py", "runserver")
```

but i want to run it from kivy in android and android don't have python builtin

django local server is using as serverside of webwiew.

i find runpy module but it can't run django.

how can i do this ?

edit 1 :

i do it like that Tomasz Jakub Rup say but not work and give below error :

```
    Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  3 2016, 09:29:07) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import django
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sample.settings'
>>> if hasattr(django, 'setup'):
...     django.setup()
... 
>>> from django.core.management import call_command
>>> call_command('runserver')
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

Comment: Why? If you need data from your website in your Android application then just expose an api

Comment: no i dont want show my web site . i want to show local website !

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. It sounds like you're trying to use django to solve a problem that you shouldn't be using django for

Comment: kivy not support rtl languages and i want create a webapp using kivyies webwiew because html support it . i want use django  for controll the content of html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You must init `django`:

```
import os

import django

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'testapp.settings'
if hasattr(django, 'setup'):
    django.setup()

from django.core.management import call_command
```

And run command:

```
call_command('runserver')
```

Comment: i do it same as above but give this error at latest line    :    /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Comment: @KamRad Please edit question and enter script and full traceback

Comment: i using pythn 3.5 and django 1.9

Comment: @KamRad You cannot run this from shell. save this code to file and run this file. Shell does not have `__main__` variable

Comment: but i want run it from another python script

Answer (score 0):

Built in development server of django is fine initially but down the line you might want to use uwsgi or gunicorn to serve your application. They are efficient and can also be made to run on startup in the background rather than launching the shell and you having to run the command manually. You can check more about it here.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: can you give mi some hint about run uwsgi on android . thanks

Comment: Im exactly not sure of why you would want a web server on your mobile, you could rather use some cloud platforms like heroku or pythonanywhere to host your apps. Anyway, you could have a look at it as I'm not sure of any readily available solution for your requirements - http://pypi.qpython.org/index.php/qpython-django/